# DV-2019 reset before October 18?

Tags: usa, immigration

There is a series of viral emails going around Turkish sites claiming that the DV-2019 lottery was flawed and others should reapply.

The source of this seems to be [United States of America, Department of State U.S. Embassy & Consulate in Ecuador](https://ec.usembassy.gov/), which put out an article called [*"New Entry Period for Diversity Visa Program DV-2019"*](https://ec.usembassy.gov/new-entry-period-diversity-visa-program-dv-2019/).

Is this valid for everyone? I don't see it mentioned on the [Electronic Diversity Visa Lottery](https://dvlottery.state.gov/) website at all.

Comment: The [DV lottery website](https://www.dvlottery.state.gov/) now says down for maintenance (15 oct 2017), so this may very well be true. However, the Ecuador site says that any applicant that already applied will get an email to check the website so I would just wait for it.

Answer (score 1):

And, as of 16 October 2017, the main [Diversity Visa website](https://dvlottery.state.gov/) is still down for maintenance but now has information:

> Due to a technical issue, the DV-2019 entry period that began on
>   October 3 has been closed. Entries submitted during October 3-10 are
>   not valid and have been excluded from the system; they will not count
>   as a duplicate entry. The technical issue has been resolved and a new
>   full entry period will begin at noon, U.S. Eastern Daylight Time on
>   Wednesday October 18, 2017 and will run until noon Eastern Standard
>   Time on Wednesday November 22, 2017. Only entries submitted during
>   this period will be accepted and considered for selection in the
>   lottery. Please throw away any confirmation number or other
>   documentation that you have if you submitted an entry during Oct.
>   3-10.